# What is the most elegant way of bubble-sorting in F#?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, f#

What is the most elegant way of bubble-sorting in F#?

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in one of the answers, bubble sorting isn't efficient in a functional language to begin with. A humourously-cynical commenter also pointed out that bubble sorting is only appropriate when the list is small and it's almost sorted anyway.

However, I'm curious to see how a clever bubble-sort can be written in F#, since I've done bubble sorts in C#, C++, and Java EE in the past, and since I'm an F# newbie.

Comment: +1 for the humor in using the terms "elegant" and "bubble-sort" in the same sentence

Comment: bubble sorting is efficient if the set is small, and is almost sorted.

Comment: F#, elegant? Hah, +1 for humor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using bubble sort in a functional language isn't very efficient, because the implementation has to reverse the list many times (and this can't be really implemented very efficiently for immutable lists).

Anyway, the example from Erlang can be rewritten to F# like this:

```
let sort l = 
  let rec sortUtil acc rev l =
    match l, rev with
    | [], true -> acc |> List.rev
    | [], false -> acc |> List.rev |> sortUtil [] true
    | x::y::tl, _ when x > y -> sortUtil (y::acc) false (x::tl)
    | hd::tl, _ -> sortUtil (hd::acc) rev tl
  sortUtil [] true l
```

On the other side, you can implement the same algorithm using mutable arrays. This will be more efficient and in F# you can work with arrays too if you want. The following function creates a copy of the array and sorts it.

```
let sort (arr:'a[]) = 
  let arr = arr |> Array.copy
  let swap i j = let tmp = arr.[i] in arr.[i] <- arr.[j]; arr.[j] <- tmp
  for i = arr.Length - 1 downto 0 do
    for j = 1 to i do
      if (arr.[j - 1] > arr.[j]) then swap (j-1) j
  arr
```

Tomas

Comment: "The example from Erlang"  
http://en.literateprograms.org/Special:Downloadcode/Bubble_sort_(Erlang   <-- SO's HTML is broken, please add a closing parenthesis yourself.

Answer (score 2):

F# is an impure language. Don't be puritanical about purity. Here is a simpler and more elegant impure bubblesort in F#:

```
let rec sort (a: int []) =
  let mutable fin = true
  for i in 0..a.Length-2 do
    if a.[i] > a.[i+1] then
      let t = a.[i]
      a.[i] <- a.[i+1]
      a.[i+1] <- t
      fin <- false
  if not fin then sort a
```