# What is the most elegant way of shell sorting (comb / diminishing increment sorting) in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, design-patterns, shellsort

Is there a better way to shell sort using C#?

```
// array of integers to hold values
private int[] a = new int[100];

// number of elements in array
private int count;

// Shell Sort Algorithm
public void sortArray()
{
  int i, j, increment, temp;

  increment = 3;

  while( increment > 0 )
  {
    for( i=0; i < count; i++ )
    {
      j = i;
      temp = a[i];

      while( (j >= increment) && (a[j-increment] > temp) )
      {
        a[j] = a[j - increment];
        j = j - increment;
      }

      a[j] = temp;
    }

    if( increment/2 != 0 )
    {
      increment = increment/2;
    }
    else if( increment == 1 )
    {
      increment = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      increment = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, I'm wondering because I have some different examples of 'elegant' sorts in different languages (like bubble sorting in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595244/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-bubble-sort-in-c) and [F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279145/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-of-bubble-sorting-in-f)), and I'm comparing them. In real life, I'd probably use the following most of the time in C#:

```
Array.Sort( object[] )
```

I don't care if these are 'academic' and non-pragmatic patterns. You can down-mod me into oblivion if you want :)

KA

Comment: +1 for "You can down-mod me into oblivion if you want :)" - made me laugh :)

Comment: What is the meaning of "x" in this algorithm? Is it supposed to be intialized to a.Length or something?

Comment: @Eric: Count. As Jon Skeet pointed out, it really should actually say 'count' instead of x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improvements you could very easily make:

- Don't keep state in the object. This should be easy to do just with local variables.
- Use conventional C# names like `ShellSort` rather than `shellSort`
- Use meaningful names like `count` instead of `x`
- Use the conditional operator, e.g.

  ```
  // This replaces your last 12 lines
  int halfIncrement = increment / 2;
  increment = halfIncrement != 0 ? halfIncrement : 1 - increment;
  ```
- Make the code generic - why restrict yourself to integers?
- Make your method take the data in question, and make it an `IList<T>`
- Make the sort order arbitrary via an `IComparer<T>`, providing an overload which uses the default.
- Declare variables as late as possible to reduce their scope and improve readability

Very little of this is actually sort-related - I haven't verified whether your code is actually a legitimate shell sort or not...

Comment: Do you like, have a life outside Stack Overflow or are you some kind of AI program invented by Google?

Comment: Along the same lines, another possible language-oriented improvement may be to expose ShellSort() as an extension method of IList<T> to allow fluent usage in LINQ queries and the like.

Comment: Gary, in order for me to tell you the truth, you'd have to sign one of Google's terrifying NDA's, so perhaps it's best if you never know.

Answer (score 0):

In my test this is 75% to %90 faster than array sort with the same System.Func comparer. I use  it to sort a custom struct. you can easily modify it to sort classes.

```
public class DualQuickSort<T> where T : struct
    {
        private readonly System.Func<T, T, int> comparer;
        public DualQuickSort(System.Func<T, T, int> comparer)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }

    public DualQuickSort(IComparer<T> comparer)
        : this(comparer.Compare)
    {

    }

    public  void Sort(T[] a)
    {
        Sort(a, 0, a.Length);
    }
    public  void Sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        RangeCheck(a.Length, fromIndex, toIndex);

        DualPivotQuicksort(a, fromIndex, toIndex - 1, 3);
    }
    private static void RangeCheck(int length, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        if (fromIndex > toIndex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("fromIndex > toIndex");
        }
        if (fromIndex < 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(fromIndex + " is less than 0");
        }
        if (toIndex > length)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(toIndex + " is greater than " + fromIndex);
        }
    }

    private static void Swap(T[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        var temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
    private  void DualPivotQuicksort(T[] a, int left, int right, int div)
    {
        var len = right - left;

        if (len < 27)
        { // insertion sort for tiny array
            for (var i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
            {
                for (var j = i; j > left && comparer(a[j] , a[j - 1])==-1; j--)

                {
                    Swap(a, j, j - 1);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        var third = len / div;
        // "medians"
        var m1 = left + third;
        var m2 = right - third;
        if (m1 <= left)
        {
            m1 = left + 1;
        }
        if (m2 >= right)
        {
            m2 = right - 1;
        }
        if (comparer(a[m1] , a[m2])==-1)
        {
            Swap(a, m1, left);
            Swap(a, m2, right);
        }
        else
        {
            Swap(a, m1, right);
            Swap(a, m2, left);
        }
        // pivots
        var pivot1 = a[left];
        var pivot2 = a[right];
        // pointers
        var less = left + 1;
        var great = right - 1;
        // sorting
        for (var k = less; k <= great; k++)
        {
            if (comparer(a[k] , pivot1)==-1)
            {
                Swap(a, k, less++);
            }
            else if (comparer(a[k], pivot2) == 1)
            {
                while (k < great && comparer(a[great] , pivot2)==1)
                {
                    great--;
                }
                Swap(a, k, great--);
                if (comparer(a[k], pivot1) == -1)
                {
                    Swap(a, k, less++);
                }
            }
        }
        // Swaps
        var dist = great - less;
        if (dist < 13)
        {
            div++;
        }
        Swap(a, less - 1, left);
        Swap(a, great + 1, right);
        // subarrays
        DualPivotQuicksort(a, left, less - 2, div);
        DualPivotQuicksort(a, great + 2, right, div);

        // equal elements
        if (dist > len - 13 && comparer(pivot1,pivot2)!=0)
        {
            for (int k = less; k <= great; k++)
            {
                if (comparer(a[k] , pivot1)==0)
                {
                    Swap(a, k, less++);
                }
                else if (comparer(a[k], pivot2) == 0)
                {
                    Swap(a, k, great--);
                    if (comparer(a[k], pivot1) == 0)
                    {
                        Swap(a, k, less++);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // subarray
        if (comparer(pivot1 , pivot2)==-1)
        {
            DualPivotQuicksort(a, less, great, div);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That range check is getting mighty famous these days ;)

Comment: How is this about `the most elegant way to shell sort using C#`?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code. Automatically it will calculate the distance and distance will be calculated on consideration of maximum three lists would generate.

```
using System;

namespace ShellSortExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] num = { 70, 30, 40, 10, 80, 20, 90, 110, 75, 60, 45, 199, 35, 2, 31, 22, 1, 11, 211, 100, 23, 55, 50 };
            WriteList("Unsorted List", num);
            int distance = 0;
            // Generate the distance as per the length of the list
            //It will consider maximum 3 list should generate
            for (int i = 1; i < num.Length; i++)
            {
                var div = num.Length / i;
                // Maximum 3 list should be generate
                if (div <= 3)
                {
                    distance = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Do the grouping and Apply insertion sort
            for (int i = distance; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int tmpListVal = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < num.Length;)
                {
                    int tmpVal = num[j];
                    //Applying insertion sort with each shell/group element
                    for (int k = j - i; k >= 0; k -= i)
                    {
                        if (k <= num.Length - 1 && tmpVal < num[k])
                        {
                            num[k + i] = num[k];
                            num[k] = tmpVal;
                        }
                    }
                    if (j + i >= num.Length)
                    {
                        j = tmpListVal + 1;
                        tmpListVal = j;
                        if (j == i)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j += i;
                    }
                }
            }
            WriteList("After applied shell sort",num);
        }
        static void WriteList(string msg, int[] list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{msg} : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($" {list[i]}");
            }
            Console.Write("\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain why this is in any way better than the code in the question.

Comment: What gap sequence will this use, and how does it compare to [other gap sequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences)?